# How do I respond, friend refers me in an email to recruiters & CC'd me

Tags: job-search, new-job, recruitment, entry-level

Last week I met a recruiter "Joe" (at a career fair) from a company my old classmate works for. I've applied for XY position, and my awesome friend sends an email to the same recruiter Joe, & CC'd me in as well (attaching my resume).

-How should I respond?
-Should I wait for the recruiters to send an email?
-I drafted a follow up email to the same recruiter Joe, should I send it out separately?

Comment: Why does your friend have a copy of your resume?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: **What** did your friend send to the recruiter (what's in the email)? Please [edit] your question and make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

> -How should I respond? -Should I wait for the recruiters to send an email? -I drafted a follow up email to the same recruiter Joe, should
>   I send it out separately?

Considering you didn't write the email, but were just CC'd on it, I'd hold off on writing a follow up for now. If the recruiter is interested, they'll contact you (I assume either the resume contains contact data or the recruiter will use the CC'd email).

In future, unless you're dealing with references by the friend (these are usually informal) its better to send your CV/Resume yourself, and not have a friend do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend CC'd you so that you won't be surprised if you get a call from the recruiter. And the recruiter can see that you have been CC'd so she or he knows that you know they have your CV and that you won't be surprised when they call you. It just makes things easier all around for everyone.

There is nothing else that you need to do.